# Google sheets Array not filling

Tags: google-sheets

I have a simple formula I am using to concatenate to create a unique ref ID.
The formula does not fill the cell below it.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( CONCATENATE(LEFT(E2,1),
                           mid(C2,find(" ",B2,2)+3,3),
                           MID(E2,3,1),left(B2,1),RIGHT(E2,1),
                           RIGHT(B2,1),right(E2,2)
                          )
             )
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a chance... give it a range! Arrayformula works on Ranges, while you gave it only single cells in your arguments. Probably you want something like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( CONCATENATE(LEFT(E2:E10,1),
                       mid(C2:C10,find(" ",B2:B10,2)+3,3),
                       MID(E2:E10,3,1),left(B2:B10,1),RIGHT(E2:E10,1),
                       RIGHT(B2:B10,1),right(E2:E10,2)
                      )
         )
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice and suggestion

Comment: When you like an answer, it's customary to upvote and/or accept it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You must give a range to use arrayformula. And I suggest using & instead of concatenate like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LEFT(E2:E6,1)&mid(C2:C6,find(" ",B2:B6,2)+3,3)&MID(E2:E6,3,1)&left(B2:B6,1)&RIGHT(E2:E6,1)&RIGHT(B2:B6,1)&right(E2:E6,2))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help the formula worked as you said and also helped me understand how to use it